# if row has value in datagridview, insert data in the next row

Tags: vb.net

i got two datagridview, in dgv1 i got a button that deletes a selected row and transfer the selected row to my 2nd dgv2, the problem is, on the 2nd time i delete a row, it overwrites the row that i deleted

i tried  multiple codes but it just ends up on the same problem

```
Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
Dim nextrow As New DataGridViewRow
   For Each row In DataGridView3.Rows
   For Each nextrow In DataGridView3.Rows


    If row.Index <> nextrow.Index Then
    If row.Cells(0).Value = nextrow.Cells(0).Value AndAlso 
    row.Cells(2).Value = nextrow.Cells(2).Value AndAlso row.Cells(3).Value 
    = nextrow.Cells(3).Value AndAlso row.Cells(8).Value = 
    nextrow.Cells(8).Value Then

    DataGridView3.Rows.Remove(row)
    DataGridView3.Rows.Remove(nextrow)

    End If
    End If

      Next

    Next
```

it works at 1st try but in the 2nd time it overwrites the data from my dgv2
i want to display my deleted data from my dgv1 to dgv2

Answer (score 0):

When you work with collections and you're removing items, one good technique is to walk backward through the collection instead of forward.  This is because if you remove/delete one item in a collection, it can change the collection.  For example, you delete Item 4 and so Item 5 becomes Item 4 then you try to do something with Item 5 but it is now Item 6 etc.

To eliminate this problem, try something like:

```
Dim myrows As Integer = gvw.rows.count
Dim row as GridViewRow, rownext as GridViewRow
For myrow As Integer = myrows -1  To 0 Step -1
  row = gvw.rows(myrow)
  rownext gvw.rows(myrow - 1)

  'Do some comparison

  If .. Then
    gvw.rows.Remove(myrow) 'you can remove it because it is the last row
  End If
  If myrow = 1 Then Exit For 'cannot go lower
Next
```